Windows Zabbix 6.4 active agent monitoring
I am trying to monitor a Windows Server2019 using a Zabbix agent active, because it has no hyper-v or vcenter in which we can install and configure a monitoring proxy.
I have installed the Zabbix agent 6.4 (same version that the Zabbix Server has) on it, but on the part in which you have to type the Zabbix Server, I have typed the DNS address of my Zabbix server.
And at the time of adding it to the Zabbix server, I have done the following:
In the hostname part, I added the same hostname of the SERVER.
On the template Part, I have added de Windows By Zabbix Agent template.
On the part of the interfaces, I have typed the loopback IP address (127.0.0.1).

Where it says Monitored By... I have selected: no proxy. Despite doing all of that. Once I check the latest data part, on the part where it says Operating System, I get Linux Server (Operating system of the machine where I have the Zabbix Server machine).
So I am not getting the correct information of the Windows Server which I am trying to monitor, like the correct operating system, how much free disk space does this server have, etc.
What might be the problem?
What do I have to change?

What is in the log files in the client and server?

16888:20230704:111827.656 Failed to initialize builtin counter: % Processor Time
16888:20230704:111827.657 Failed to initialize builtin counter: Total Sessions
4312:20230704:111828.296 agent #5 started [active checks #1]
4312:20230704:111829.299 Unable to connect to [127.0.0.1]:10051 [cannot connect to [[127.0.0.1]:10051]: Connection refused.]
4312:20230704:111829.300 Unable to send heartbeat message to [127.0.0.1]:10051 [cannot connect to [[127.0.0.1]:10051]: Connection refused.]
Unable to connect to [127.0.0.1]:10051 [cannot connect to [[127.0.0.1]:10051]: Connection refused.]

These are the logs of the zabbix agentd log that is allocated on the client. Thank you

I have added the ip address of my zabbix server on the ServerActive= part of  the zabbix_agentd.conf file of the client. and on the log i got the following:  Unable to connect to [10.13.0.5]:10051 [cannot connect to [[10.13.0.5]:10051]: (null)]
Unable to send heartbeat message to [10.13.0.5]:10051
[cannot connect to [[10.13.0.5]:10051]: (null)]
Unable to connect to [10.13.0.5]:10051
[cannot connect to [[10.13.0.5]:10051]: (null)]
Active check configuration update started to fail
